# How to stop tinymce convert an image url into img?

Tags: tinymce

The queston is in the tittle. When I paste an image url into the textarea tinymce converts it into the image, How to force it leave only link?

Answer (score 0):

Testing this on TinyMCE 4, on the [full featured example](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/) given in the TinyMCE documentation, this does not seem to happen... When I paste an image URL there, the URL keeps there, no image replaces it.

What version of TinyMCE do you have? Do you have any custom plugin? Maybe this is being triggered by custom code?

Comment: @Дмитрий Did this have any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the plugin "paste"